# Cannot add WatchOS target to React Native App

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-watch

I have developed a couple of watch apps and I am getting the hang of it, but when I try to add a watch os target to a React Native App I get 47 errors that I do not understand.

I am attempting to follow this [tutorial - How to add an Apple Watch Extension To your react native application](https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/how-to-add-an-apple-watch-extension-to-your-react-native-application).

### Steps to Reproduce

#### 1. Create a new React Native Project

First, I created a new React Native Project. (success ✅)

```
react-native init RNWithAppleWatch
```

#### 2. Build and Run the React Native Project

Then I can build and run the project. (success ✅)

```
cd RNWtihAppleWatch; npm run ios;
```

#### 3. Open the Project Workspace and add a Target

Next, I open the workspace file. At this point the React Native app builds and runs from xCode without issue too.

[image: Open Workspace]

Inside the workspace I select the main project and click the `+` under targets.

[image: Targets]

From here I select `watchOS` and `Watch App for iOS App`:

[image: Select Target]

With the following settings:

[image: Create Watch App]

And I activate the target when asked:

[image: Activate Target]

And the Target is created.

#### 6. Run the Watch Target

This is where the problems begin to surface. The first thing I notice is there is one error in the `WatchApp Extension` after the target is created:

[image: First Error]

There is some sort of problem Compiling Swift Sources?

If I try to run the `WatchApp` target in the simulator I get 47 errors:

[image: Errors]

How can I resolve these errors and run a basic `Hello World` with React Native and Apple Watch?

### Package Versions

- react-native  0.63.3
- xCode           12.0.1
- macOS Catalina  10.15.6

### Full Error Text

```
Ld /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/WatchApp\ Extension normal arm64 (in target 'WatchApp Extension' from project 'RNWithAppleWatch')
    cd /Users/xxx/Projects/learning/RNWithAppleWatch/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-watchos7.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/watchsimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/watchsimulator -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/xxx/Debug-watchsimulator -filelist /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WatchApp\ Extension.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WatchApp\ Extension_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fapplication-extension -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/watchsimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WatchApp_Extension.swiftmodule -e _WKExtensionMain -framework WatchKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/WatchApp\ Extension.appex-Simulated.xcent -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WatchApp\ Extension_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNWithAppleWatch-axogcnukcxagprhcahugtcdatqdx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNWithAppleWatch.build/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/WatchApp\ Extension

ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftHomeKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftWatchKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSceneKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMapKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreLocation'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "value witness table for Builtin.Int64", referenced from:
      full type metadata for __C.CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior in ComplicationController.o
  "nominal type descriptor for Foundation.Date", referenced from:
      _symbolic _____Sg 10Foundation4DateV in ComplicationController.o
  "_swift_getForeignTypeMetadata", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __C.CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior in ComplicationController.o
  "static (extension in Foundation):Swift.Array._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSArray?) -> [A]", referenced from:
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.handleSharedComplicationDescriptors([__C.CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> () in ComplicationController.o
  "(extension in Foundation):Swift.Array._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSArray", referenced from:
      reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSArray) -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [__C.CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> () in ComplicationController.o
      reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSArray?) -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [__C.CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> () in ComplicationController.o
  "_swift_allocObject", referenced from:
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getComplicationDescriptors(handler: ([__C.CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getTimelineEndDate(for: __C.CLKComplication, withHandler: (Foundation.Date?) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getPrivacyBehavior(for: __C.CLKComplication, withHandler: (__C.CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getCurrentTimelineEntry(for: __C.CLKComplication, withHandler: (__C.CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getTimelineEntries(for: __C.CLKComplication, after: Foundation.Date, limit: Swift.Int, withHandler: ([__C.CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
      @objc WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for: __C.CLKComplication, withHandler: (__C.CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
  "Swift.String.init(_builtinStringLiteral: Builtin.RawPointer, utf8CodeUnitCount: Builtin.Word, isASCII: Builtin.Int1) -> Swift.String", referenced from:
      WatchApp_Extension.ComplicationController.getComplicationDescriptors(handler: ([__C.CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> ()) -> () in ComplicationController.o
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is React Native is Objective-C and the WatchOS App is SWIFT. My problems is I learned Swift, not Objective-C. Is it possible to have a Swift Target co-exist with an Objective-C target?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the **Library Search Paths** Build Setting.

In your project select the Watch Extension Target, then Build Settings Menu, and find the **Library Search Paths** setting. (You need to make sure the "All" filter is selected or you will not see this setting). In it's value you'll see two links, use the first one only...  Set the value ov **Library Search Paths** to: `"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`

This worked for me

Comment: I've got this exact issue, but this path was already listed under Library Search Paths. Is there anything else you tried to get it to work?

Comment: I have the same exact issue as @DeeBo too, the path "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)" was already listed under Library Search Paths.

Comment: @HoangLM Please check the answer I just posted. I was able to resolve our mutual issue.

Comment: Awesome! Baffling that this is an issue, and I don't really know _how_ the solution works, but I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Wow Awesome. I was stuck with the same issue for days and voila you saved me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 8):

When I came across this, the path @Tabbyofjudah suggested was already present in the list,

I actually solved this by *deleting* the contents of Library Search Paths for the watchOS extension. Leaving it looking like this:

[image: Empty Search Paths]

And my project now builds (not just as a bodge, all the way to App Store Connect). Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: Thanks! I would have never tried this without seeing this. Seems to be building fine

Comment: The below marked answer with a check was already in my path list, as the other person mentioned. But this answer is what ended up letting my project build.